# Convergence of weighted regression solution to the solution of L1 regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, weighted-regression, least-absolute-deviations

I have read in [this paper](http://article.sapub.org/10.5923.j.statistics.20150503.02.html) that the weighted regression solution converges to the solution of L1 regression,

for weights, $$W_i=1/|y_i-\hat y_i|$$

I worked this out but unfortunately, I lost.

Could anyone provide me with a reference that includes this derivation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

minimize the sum of squared errors $\sum_i \epsilon_i(\theta)^2$ with $\epsilon_i(\theta) = y_i - \mathbf x_i^\top \theta$ which is simply ordinary least squares estimation for $\theta$.  But clearly $$\sum_i \epsilon_i(\theta)^2 = \sum_i \lvert\epsilon_i(\theta)\lvert^2$$

now use weights and observe that $\lvert y_i - \hat y_i(\theta)\lvert = \lvert \epsilon_i(\theta)\lvert$ then with weights $w_i=1/\lvert y_i - \hat y_i(\theta)\lvert$ it follows that 
$$\sum_i \epsilon_i(\theta)^2w_i = \sum_i \lvert\epsilon_i(\theta)\lvert^2w_i= \sum_i \lvert\epsilon_i(\theta)\lvert^2/\lvert y_i - \hat y_i(\theta)\lvert= \sum_i \lvert\epsilon_i(\theta)\lvert^2/\lvert \epsilon(\theta)\lvert =\sum_i \lvert\epsilon_i(\theta)\lvert$$
which is LAD.

Admittedly this in itself does not answer why you get convergence but that should follow from convergence results on Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares (IRLS) see this wiki [IRLS on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares)